# SQL database design for sharing (or reblogging) a user's content

Tags: sql, sql-server, facebook, twitter, database-design

Using MS SQL Server 2014. I want to design a content share feature on a website. Facebook calls it 'Share', Twitter calls it 'Re-Tweet' and Tumblr calls it 'Reblog'. What would the database design be to share user's content with other member's posts, but keeping the original poster as the source of the content? Do I create another table for the shared posts? If I have to make a 'share' table, what would the 'shared' table structure be composed of? What would the query be to show posts whether or not there is a share? Whats the best way to do this?

Given the simplified tables below

```
content                        Users
--------------------------     --------------------------
contentnum BIGINT IDENTITY     usernum BIGINT
usernum BIGINT                 firstname NVARCHAR(30)
comment NVARCHAR(500)          firstname NVARCHAR(30)
views BIGINT
created DATETIME
```

Simplified query to get rows

```
SELECT contentnum, c.usernum, comment, created, firstname, lastname FROM content c
INNER JOIN users u ON c.usernum=u.usernum
ORDER BY contentnum
```

### Scenario

1. Sally makes a post that says 'Beer is good stuff'
2. Tom 'shares' Sally's post
3. Under Tom's posts it should say 'Beer is good stuff'- Original poster Sally
4. Sally's views increase by 1 for every view whether another member sees Sally's 'original post' or a 'shared post of the original'

Answer (score 0):

Create a Shares table that links Users (who do the sharing) with Content.

Then multiple users can share multiple posts.

The rest of the points in your scenario can be calculated in the business layer.